# GOLang posts to a Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, go

I have a golang program sending an item every second (as a post) to a server. A Golang listening program outputs the items as a hash:

```
{"Address":"test@test.com", "EmailType":"test", "Event":"test", "Timestamp":1234}.
```

Now I want to send this data to a rails server and save each event to a database. However when I point the program to my post route I get this error:

```
Started POST "/items" for ::1 at 2016-08-23 00:36:17 +0200

Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML

Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The error is get on the golang program is:

```
Sending events to: http://localhost:4000/items
2016/08/23 00:36:17 Expecting 200 returned, got %!f(int=422)
```

Can anybody help me out with whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to disable CSRF verification for the `ItemsController#create` action.

In your `ItemsController`.

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]
```